# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved'

Tags: next.js, solidity, nft, hardhat, openzeppelin

i try to write NFT marketplace and i have problem with reselling items from user that buy item from owner and new, third user.
I use next.js + openzeppelin + hardhat + infura and metamask.
Creating and buying NFT is successful, all params on sell-item.js page getting correctly.

This is my function in NFTMarket.sol:

```
function resellToken(address nftContract, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) public payable {
      require(idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner == msg.sender, "Only item owner can perform this operation");
      require(msg.value == listingPrice, "Price must be equal to listing price");
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].sold = false;
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].price = price;
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].seller = payable(msg.sender);
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner = payable(address(this));
      _itemsSold.decrement();

      IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
    }
```

This is my web page:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import axios from 'axios'
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal'

import {
    nftaddress, nftmarketaddress
} from '../config'

// import NFT from '../artifacts/contracts/NFT.sol/NFT.json'
import NFTMarket from '../artifacts/contracts/NFTMarket.sol/NFTMarket.json'

export default function ResellNFT() {
  const [formInput, updateFormInput] = useState({ price: '', image: '' })
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id, tokenUri } = router.query
  const { image, price } = formInput

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNFT()
  }, [id])

  async function fetchNFT() {
    if (!tokenUri) return
    const meta = await axios.get(tokenUri)
    updateFormInput(state => ({ ...state, image: meta.data.image }))
  }

  async function listNFTForSale() {
    if (!price) return
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
    const signer = provider.getSigner()

    const priceFormatted = ethers.utils.parseUnits(formInput.price, 'ether')
    const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, NFTMarket.abi, signer)
    //const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, provider)
    let listingPrice = await marketContract.getListingPrice()    

    listingPrice = listingPrice.toString()
    let transaction = await marketContract.resellToken(nftaddress, id, priceFormatted, { value: listingPrice })
    await transaction.wait()
   
    router.push('/')
    
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-col pb-12">
        <input
          placeholder="Asset Price in Eth"
          className="mt-2 border rounded p-4"
          onChange={e => updateFormInput({ ...formInput, price: e.target.value })}
        />
        {
          image && (
            <img className="rounded mt-4" width="350" src={image} />
          )
        }
        <button onClick={listNFTForSale} className="font-bold mt-4 bg-pink-500 text-white rounded p-4 shadow-lg">
          List NFT
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Error code:

```
    eth_estimateGas
  Contract call:       NFTMarket#resellToken
  From:                0x1cbd3b2770909d4e10f157cabc84c7264073c9ec
  To:                  0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3
  Value:               0.025 ETH

  Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved'
      at NFT.transferFrom (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol:156)
      at NFTMarket.resellToken (contracts/NFTMarket.sol:89)
      at EthModule._estimateGasAction (E:\маркетплейс\polygon-ethereum\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:425:7)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider._sendWithLogging (E:\маркетплейс\polygon-ethereum\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:139:22)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (E:\маркетплейс\polygon-ethereum\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:116:18)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleRequest (E:\маркетплейс\polygon-ethereum\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:188:20) 
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleSingleRequest (E:\маркетплейс\polygon-ethereum\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:167:17)
      at Server.JsonRpcHandler.handleHttp (E:\маркетплейс\polygon-ethereum\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:52:21)
```

---

UPDATE:
This is my smart contract of the marketplace

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract NFTMarket is ReentrancyGuard {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter private _itemIds;
  Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;

  address payable owner;
  uint256 listingPrice = 0.025 ether;

  constructor() {
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
  }

  struct MarketItem {
    uint256 itemId;
    address nftContract;
    uint tokenId;
    address payable seller;
    address payable owner;
    uint256 price;
    bool sold;
  }

  mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private idToMarketItem;

  event MarketItemCreated (
    uint256 indexed itemId,
    address indexed nftContract,
    uint256 indexed tokenId,
    address seller,
    address owner,
    uint256 price,
    bool sold
  );

  function getListingPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
   return listingPrice;
  }

  function createMarketItem(
    address nftContract,
    uint256 tokenId,
    uint256 price
  ) public payable nonReentrant {
    require(price > 0, "Price must be at least 1 wei");
    require(msg.value == listingPrice, "Price must be equal to listing price");

    _itemIds.increment();
    uint256 itemId = _itemIds.current();

    idToMarketItem[tokenId] = MarketItem(
      itemId,
      nftContract,
      tokenId,
      payable(msg.sender),
      payable(address(0)),
      price,
      false
    );

    IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);

    emit MarketItemCreated(
      itemId,
      nftContract,
      tokenId,
      msg.sender,
      address(0),
      price,
      false
    );
  }

  function resellToken(address nftContract, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) public payable {
      require(idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner == msg.sender, "Only item owner can perform this operation");
      require(msg.value == listingPrice, "Price must be equal to listing price");
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].sold = false;
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].price = price;
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].seller = payable(msg.sender);
      idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner = payable(address(this));
      _itemsSold.decrement();

      IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
    }

  function createMarketSale(
    address nftContract,
    uint256 itemId
    ) public payable nonReentrant {
    uint price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;
    uint tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;
    require(msg.value == price, "Please sumbit the asking price in order to complete the purchase");

    idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);
    IERC721 (nftContract).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
    idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
    idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;
    _itemsSold.increment();
    payable(owner).transfer(listingPrice);
  }

  function fetchMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
    uint ItemCount = _itemIds.current();
    uint unsoldItemCount = _itemIds.current() - _itemsSold.current();
    uint currentIndex = 0;

    MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](unsoldItemCount);
    for (uint i = 0; i < ItemCount; i++) {
      if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == address(0)) {
        uint currentId = idToMarketItem[i + 1].itemId;
        MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
        items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
        currentIndex += 1;
      }
    }
    return items;
  }

   function fetchMyNFTs() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
    uint totalItemCount = _itemIds.current();
    uint itemCount = 0;
    uint currentIndex = 0;

    for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
      if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
        itemCount += 1;
      }
    }

    MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
    for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
      if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
        uint currentId = idToMarketItem[i + 1].itemId;
        MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
        items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
        currentIndex += 1;
      }
    }
    return items;
  }

  function fetchItemsCreated() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
    uint totalItemCount = _itemIds.current();
    uint itemCount = 0;
    uint currentIndex = 0;

    for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
      if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
        itemCount += 1;
      }
    }

    MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
    for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
      if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
        uint currentId = idToMarketItem[i + 1].itemId;
        MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
        items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
        currentIndex += 1;
      }
    }
    return items;
  }
}
```

This is the nfc creation code

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { create as ipfsHttpClient } from 'ipfs-http-client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal'
import {MPLayout} from '../../components/MPLayout'

const client = ipfsHttpClient('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0')

import {
    nftaddress, nftmarketaddress
} from '../../config'

import NFT from '../../artifacts/contracts/NFT.sol/NFT.json'
import NFTMarket from '../../artifacts/contracts/NFTMarket.sol/NFTMarket.json'

export default function CreateItem () {
    const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState(null)
    const [formInput, updateFormInput] = useState({ price: '', name: '', description: '' })
    const router = useRouter()

    async function onChange(e) {
        const file = e.target.files[0] 
        try {
            const added = await client.add(
                file,
                {
                    progress: (prog) => console.log('received: ${prog}')
                }
            )
            const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}`
            setFileUrl(url)
        }   catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    async function createItem() {
        const { name, description, price } = formInput
        if (!name || !description || !price || !fileUrl) return
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            name, description, image: fileUrl
        })

        try {
            const added = await client.add(data)
            const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}`
            /* after file is uploaded to IPFS, return the URL to use it in the transaction */
            createSale(url)
        }   catch (error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file: ', error)
        }
    }

    async function createSale(url) {
        const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
        const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()

        let contract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, signer)
        let transaction = await contract.createToken(url)
        let tx = await transaction.wait()

        let event = tx.events [0]
        let value = event.args[2]
        let tokenId = value.toNumber()

        const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(formInput.price, 'ether')

        contract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, NFTMarket.abi, signer)
        let listingPrice = await contract.getListingPrice()
        listingPrice = listingPrice.toString()

        transaction = await contract.createMarketItem(nftaddress, tokenId, price, { value: listingPrice})
        await transaction.wait()
        router.push('/')
    }

    return (
            <MPLayout title={'Create Item'}>
                <div className="flex justify-center">
                    <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-col pb-12">
                    <input 
                        placeholder="Asset Name"
                        className="mt-8 border rounded p-4"
                        onChange={e => updateFormInput({ ...formInput, name: e.target.value })}
                    />
                    <textarea
                        placeholder="Asset Description"
                        className="mt-2 border rounded p-4"
                        onChange={e => updateFormInput({ ...formInput, description: e.target.value })}
                        />
                        <input
                        placeholder="Asset Price in Eth"
                        className="mt-2 border rounded p-4"
                        onChange={e => updateFormInput({ ...formInput, price: e.target.value })}
                        />
                        <input
                        type="file"
                        name="Asset"
                        className="my-4"
                        onChange={onChange}
                        />
                        {
                            fileUrl && (
                                <img className="rounded mt-4" width="350" src={fileUrl} />
                            )
                        }
                        <button 
                            onClick={createItem} 
                            className="font-bold mt-4 bg-pink-500 text-white rounded p-4 shadow-lg"
                        >
                            Create Digital Asset 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </MPLayout>
    )
    
}
```

Comment: Why is `createMarketSale()` never called? I expect it to be called by the first buyer who is going to resell it.

Comment: Hello @Ilya. Any updates on this question? I have exactly the same issue (and I am using the same sample code from the certification :-) )  setApprovalForAll() is here, the market address is properly set as an argument in the migration file #2... Your help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that somewhere else in your code after initially creating the nft, the nft is not actually owned by `idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner` but by someone else. If you're creating the nft with `_mint(...)`, your first parameter to _mint is probably wrong. If this doesn't help, can you share the code where you create the nft and also the code where you initially set `idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner`?

Comment: I added a smart contract and the year of creation of the nft

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `ERC721.sol` you have this function

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId
      ) public virtual override {

        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");  
        _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
```

You are calling this function but you are not satisfying the `require` stament:

```
require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");
```

In smart contracts, if you are transfering from another address, you have to be authorized to do it. You cannot just go transfer something from any account. So before you call `transferFrom`, you have to call this first

```
function _isApprovedOrOwner(address spender, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (bool) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: operator query for nonexistent token");
        address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
        return (spender == owner || isApprovedForAll(owner, spender) || getApproved(tokenId) == spender);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117944/why-do-i-keep-receiving-this-error-revert-erc721-transfer-caller-is-not-owner), the owner has to re-approve the NFT-market contract to change the ownership on his behalf. Add the code below in your NFT contract and call it from your FE before calling your `resellToken()` and voila !

```
    function giveResaleApproval(uint256 tokenId) public {
        require(
            ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender,
            "You must own this NFT in order to resell it"
        );
        setApprovalForAll(contractAddress, true);
        return;
    }
```